# Azure IoT Edge C++ module not sending device to cloud telemetry

Tags: c++, azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

I have written an IoT Edge C++ module that is sending the event output using the following function call:

```
bool IoTEdgeClient::sendMessageAsync(std::string message)
{
    bool retVal = false;

    LOGGER_TRACE(IOT_CONNECTION_LOG, className + "::sendMessageAsync(...) START");
    LOGGER_DEBUG(IOT_CONNECTION_LOG, className + "::sendMessageAsync(...) message : " << message);

    Poco::Mutex::ScopedLock lock(_accessMutex);

    MESSAGE_INSTANCE *messageInstance = CreateMessageInstance(message);

    IOTHUB_CLIENT_RESULT clientResult = IoTHubModuleClient_LL_SendEventToOutputAsync(_iotHubModuleClientHandle, messageInstance->messageHandle, "output1", SendConfirmationCallback, messageInstance);
    if (clientResult != IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK)
    {
        LOGGER_ERROR(IOT_CONNECTION_LOG, className + "::sendMessageAsync(...) ERROR : " << message << " Message id: " << messageInstance->messageTrackingId);
        retVal = false;
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = true;
    }

    LOGGER_TRACE(IOT_CONNECTION_LOG, className + "::sendMessageAsync(...) END");
    return retVal;
}
```

The result of the function call `IoTHubModuleClient_LL_SendEventToOutputAsync` is always coming as `IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK`. My module name is MicroServer and the route configured is:

```
FROM /messages/modules/MicroServer/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream
```

I do not see the `SendConfirmationCallback` function being called. Also, I do not see any device to cloud message appearing in the IoT hub. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I am following the coding standard as mentioned in https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_module_sender/iothub_client_sample_module_sender.c

Comment: I have also tested and found that all the required ports are open. The list of ports can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist?view=iotedge-2020-11

Comment: Did you check the logs of iotedge using command `sudo iotedge system logs -- -f`

Comment: Let me try that right away

Comment: Any luck finding the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I need to call this function atleast a couple of times per second

```
IoTHubModuleClient_LL_DoWork(_iotHubModuleClientHandle);
```

which I was not doing. As a result the code was not working properly. Once I started doing it. The code just worked.